# Error while starting apache2 service

Tags: server, apache2, services

I get an error when I run this command

`sudo service apache2 start`

This is the error

```
* Starting web server apache2                                      
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 * 
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something else running that uses port 80.
It could be another web server like nginx or another running instance of apache... might even be skype.

You can see what's using port 80 with this command:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

Comment: I think this is better suited as a comment - the command here doesn't actually solve the OP's issue, it's merely a diagnostic step.

Comment: No one else but OP has access to this machine therefore no one can tell him something like "stop service X that is running and using the port"... all he has to do is find out which service uses the port and disable it... so I think this is what the answer should look like, but if the mods think different they're free to move it or delete it...